# System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: vb.net, web-services, authorize.net

I am facing a Problem while connecting Authorise.net  to my MVC Application Using SOAP API
whenconnection establishing it shows following error

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 64.**.***.***:443 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.InvokeMethod(Method
>   TargetProcedure, Object[] Arguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags
>   Flags) at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack) at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object
>   Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[]
>   ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)

I am using SOAP API reference my code is

```
 Dim m_new_cust As New CustomerProfileWS.CustomerProfileType()
            m_new_cust.email = email
            m_new_cust.description = ""
            m_new_cust.merchantCustomerId = "6mZV4p5a96Lzx4pE"


            Dim responsecreate As CustomerProfileWS.CreateCustomerProfileResponseType = SoapAPIUtilities.Service.CreateCustomerProfile(SoapAPIUtilities.MerchantAuthentication, m_new_cust, CustomerProfileWS.ValidationModeEnum.none)
```

Comment: Function is working perfectly on Local machine,but its hows the error message on server only

Comment: Did you examine the connection log for details on why it could not make a connection?

Comment: when try to establish a connection ,it pass to catch section and shows error message,All i need to know that,is there anything else i need to to before it deploy to Server because it works perfectly on Local machine

Comment: It appears your server cannot make a secure connection to the payment gateway.  http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Authorize-Net-Begins-Infrastructure-and-SHA-2-Certificate/ba-p/49615